Why pallete and grid cell sizes differs
I created a tile map with default cell size 1,1. Then I created a palette with the same cell size but they are not the same. In the palette they do not fill the entire cell and changing the pixels per units does not affect the palette. I have the problem that the floor tiles are not the same size with the tiles that should go under so I tried to resize them in palette to fill the whole cell but in the game it was way bigger then 1 cell

